# Flutter iOS app version and build number not updating when Archiving in xCode

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, flutter-ios-build

When I archive my iOS app in xCode for uploading to the Apple appstore it stopped gettign the right version number and build number:

[image]

My pubspec.yaml has the right numbers:

```
version: 1.0.9+11
```

And it looks right in xCode but not once it gets archived:

[image]

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I needed to run `flutter build ios` before opening xcode and running archive. Now the versions numbers are correct.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! XCode 15, Flutter >=3.10.0

Comment: `flutter build ipa` also works!

Comment: Only problem with this solution is it takes too long to get the archive.

Answer (score 34):

if you still have this issue after performing the command mentioned in accepted answer you should try to edit info.plist file manually:

use below strings in `info.plist`:

For `CFBundleShortVersionString` use --> `$(MARKETING_VERSION)`

For `CFBundleVersion` use --> `$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)`

this is how i solved that issue. hope it helps.

---

**ps: assuming that you are trying to change it through Xcode**

---

Comment: this solved my issue, i didn't have to run 'flutter build ios'

Comment: solution/worked

Answer (score 9):

This is an extension to the answers of [aligur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4862911/aligur) and [samad shukr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11325112/samad-shukr). I had to change some more details to make it working again.

You need to change `ios/Runner/Info.plist` look for the keys `CFBundleShortVersionString` and `CFBundleVersion`:

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
```

And `ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`:

There are multiple lines with `CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = ...` all of them has to be replaced with `CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = "$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)";` and delete all lines with the fields `FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER` and `MARKETING_VERSION` (if those are not present you didn't messed that up)

Comment: Thanks, worked for me as well! It's even easier if you do the same through Xcode:

Go to Runner. Select Runner in "Targets" section below. Then open the Build Settings Tab and Scroll down to Versioning. Edit your Version under "Marketing Version" and Xcode will update all lines for you.

Comment: Good to know, I'm still not really familiar with xcode.

Answer (score 5):

I have solved this problem by opening `info.pilist` searching for these two keys and remove with String text

- CFBundleShortVersionString
- CFBundleVersion

---

then adding this

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>

<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
```